# Bluemix Connect and Compose - How do you use the Filter parameter for the GET (find all instances) method?

Tags: ibm-cloud, connect-compose

I just started exploring the new Bluemix Connect & Compose service, and it looks great. It should be very useful. It took no time at all to connect to my pre-existing Cloudant NoSQL DB.

The one thing I haven't been able to completely figure out in the Connect part of the service is how to use the Filter parameter on the GET (find all instances) method.  The brief description of the parameter just says "Filter defining fields, where, include, order, offset, and limit".  I successfully created the simplest possible where filter to retrieve a single instance using its ID like this:  {"where":{"id":"0fa90194e3553a0cad1207cd96531bbd"}}

The problem is that I can't get any other filter to do what I want. For example, I'd like to retrieve a list of instances, rather than just one matching one.  I'd also like to be able to retrieve an instance based on something other than its ID.

I found and read the documentation for the Salesforce connector APIs (https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/ConnectandCompose/cc_034.html#cc_026) and it helped a bit, but I still don't really get how the other filter defining fields (e.g. include, order, offset, limit) are supposed to work. My search for other docs came up pretty empty.

Any hints or pointers to other docs would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this documentation for Loopback, which is powering your API: https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Querying+data#Queryingdata-RESTsyntax (there are also entries in the left-hand menu that drill down into details about various API query operations).

For example, applying an order to your returned results might look like this:

`https://<api_url>?filter[order]=propertyName <ASC|DESC>`

Answer (score 0):

The LoopBack docs are very helpful (thanks @Matt), but it turns out that I had already interpreted the docs regarding the filter syntax provided by Bluemix correctly. It would be great if the Bluemix docs included a link to the LoopBoack docs.

The reason I thought I was using the filters incorrectly is that I was never able to retrieve more than one model instance from my Cloudant NoSQL DB. The root of my issue was that the connector being used to work with my DB (namely "loopback-connector-couch") actually modifies the DB to map data models. What this means is that the connector includes a property named "loopbackModel" in documents (model instances) in the DB and also adds a design document which effectively filters out any documents which do not include the "loopbackModel" property, so pre-existing documents may not be retrieved as expected.  I haven't had time to go back and figure out all the details of how and when the "loopbackModel" is included, but armed with this much knowledge my issue was easy to resolve and my filters/queries are now working exactly as I expect. Had I started with a new DB rather than an existing one, I never would have had any issue at all.

I personally prefer the stringified JSON syntax over the alternative REST API syntax, and figured I'd share a simple example:

My Cloudant DB is a product catalog. Each product document includes a name, a price and many other properties. To get the names and prices of the first 5 products in descending order by price, my filter is simply:

```
baseurl/product_db?filter={"fields":{"name":1,"price":1},"limit":5,"order":"price DESC"}
```

And my JSON response is:

```
[
    {"name":"DSLR Camera","price":599.95},
    {"name":"Telephoto Lens","price":29.95},
    {"name":"Wide Angle Lens","price":24.95},
    {"name":"Tripod","price":14.95},
    {"name":"UV Filter","price":4.95}
]
```

Very cool